# Python array reshape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

I am trying to reshape an array of (1000,28,28) into an array of (1000,784) where the two 28s multiply together to make the one 784 and am stuck. any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Sorry to be more specific I am trying to import the MNIST dataset as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import struct
import io
def read_idx(filename):
with open(filename,'rb',)as f:
    zero, data_type, dims = struct.unpack('>HBB', f.read(4))
    shape = tuple(struct.unpack('>I', f.read(4))[0] for d in range(dims))

    return np.fromstring(f.read(), dtype=np.uint8).reshape(shape)
data= read_idx("t10k-images.idx3-ubyte")
x=data
len(x)
a=np.array(x)
print(a.shape)
a= np.reshape(x,(1000,784))
```

Comment: Take a look at numpy.reshape: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

Comment: In the general case what are you try to accomplish? i.e Multiply all values in the list, only multiple the last two elements in a list

Comment: @KarlGraham He is not trying to multiply values, he is talking about the lengths of the two arrays, as 28 * 28 = 784

Comment: yes, not multiplying but combining the lengths

Comment: So what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If I may add to the solution bit further, this way you would achieve the same answer without having to pay attention to the exact shape of the array. In case the dimension changes tomorrow this code below will still work; as long as it remains three dimensional. Cheers!

```
arr = np.zeros((1000,28,28))
new_arr = arr.reshape(*arr.shape[:1], -1)
print(new_arr.shape)
```

Answer (score -1):

I am dumb and missed a zero this fixed everything:

```
a= np.reshape(a,(10000,784))
```